# Aggregation of Jmeter server logs in jmeter client in remote execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a situation where we need to be able to get Jmeter server logs in the client. I know that the jmeter client aggregates the reports from the server machines during remote execution. However is it possible to get hold of aggregated logs from the server machines in the client. This is to basically be able to debug Jmeter logs from all of the hosts. Unfortunately  we export Jmeter report from the jmeter client machine (to be shown  in the ci pipeline). So it would be great to have the server machine logs in the client machine.

Comment: what is the intention? is it to filter results by host ? if not clarify question as I think there is some confusion  in it.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to explain it in the question now.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to community. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter itself doesn't provide this functionality, to wit you will not be able to send `jmeter.log` files to the master from the slaves however you can use [`-j` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) to specify log file location in the slaves which will be pointing to some [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) share - i.e. location common to all the slaves, for example

- on slave 1 launch JMeter as

  ```
  java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=slave1 -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j /mounted/network/share/slave1.log
  ```
- on slave 2 launch JMeter as

  ```
  java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=slave2 -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j /mounted/network/share/slave2.log
  ```

And given `/mounted/network/share/` is accessible by all the slaves you will have logs in one single location.

Check out [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) article for more information on distributed JMeter execution tips and tricks

Answer (score 1):

Add in thread group name a prefix with machine name:

> ${__machineName()}-

This way you’ll be able in the aggregated csv file on client side to find the one that interests you.

Reference docs:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName

Comment: Thanks , but i was looking for a way to get the aggregated logs or a way to get both server and client logs. Not server specific thread group report in the aggregated report. however this is a good suggestion in scenario where one would need to know in a aggregated report the number from each servers.